# Upload the files to server whenever a new file is added or an existing file is updated

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

So basically there's a dropbox folder shared with my team members. I want to automatically upload the file which is added or upload the file which is modified. How can I do that?

Basically it'll trigger a PHP/Node file which will upload all the content of CSV file to the database.

Right now I have to manually run node command which selects the latest file from the folder and uploads it. But I want to automate this as well.
Do you think it would need a web socket?

Answer (score 1):

not sure I got you right but you might consider installing dropbox app with auto-sync or consult this link 
https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/sync-uploads/smart-sync
for more data.
Basically DropBox used to have their own API for that and they decided to remove it so I would try with app

https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/deprecating-the-sync-and-datastore-apis/

Hope that helps ...would write it in a comment but I just made an account

Best!